# SQL : query display max date (first and second max date)

Tags: mysql, sql

how to display the second oldest date of each item

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN17o.png]

the query I have only displays the maximum date:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  MAX(post_date)
FROM market_price
GROUP BY item_id
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi443.png]

how to display the second oldest/second max date of each item ?

Comment: use row_number  order by date over a derived table (with max dates)

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Giving us the text makes it **much** easier for us to help you, and that makes it more likely you'll actually get a good answer.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu That's a Sql Server thing. MySql doesn't have windowing functions like row_number

Comment: mysql 8.0 has rank https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-additions

Comment: This is a simple google away. Eg 'nth max mysql'. For a solution specifically for second google "second matx mysql'. Please read [ask].

Comment: @maSTAShuFu 8.0 is not released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work in MySQL:

```
select mp.*
from market_price mp
where mp.post_date = (select mp2.post_date
                      from market_price mp2
                      where mp2.item = mp.item
                      order by mp2.post_date
                      offset 1 limit 1
                     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Until MySQL brings window functions into a released version, you can mimic the effect of `row_number() over()` by using an ordered subquery and some variables.

Demo available at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1150f0/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE market_price 
    (`item_id` varchar(3), `post_date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO market_price 
    (`item_id`, `post_date`)
VALUES
    ('abc', '2017-12-01 00:00:00'),
    ('abc', '2017-12-02 00:00:00'),
    ('abc', '2017-12-03 00:00:00'),
    ('def', '2017-12-04 00:00:00'),
    ('def', '2017-12-05 00:00:00'),
    ('def', '2017-12-06 00:00:00'),
    ('def', '2017-12-07 00:00:00'),
    ('def', '2017-12-08 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
        item_id
      , post_date
FROM (
      SELECT
            @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=item_id,@row_num+1,1) AS rn
          , mp.item_id
          , mp.post_date
          , @prev_value := item_id
      FROM market_price mp
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
      ORDER BY
            mp.item_id
          , mp.post_date DESC
    ) d
WHERE rn = 2
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1150f0/1/0)**:

```
| item_id |            post_date |
|---------|----------------------|
|     abc | 2017-12-02T00:00:00Z |
|     def | 2017-12-07T00:00:00Z |
```

When/if `row_number() over()` is available use this:

```
select
*
from (
     select *
          , row_number() over(partition by item_id order by post_date desc) rn
     from market_price
     ) d
where rn = 2
```